# Oracle SQL Hierarchical query bottom to top

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I have ids of leafs. I need to select all id in hierarchy. Now i'm using following query:

```
select distinct id 
from table
start with id in (IDS_OF_LEAFS)
connect by id = prior pid
```

But maybe it can be done another way without distinct and traversal full hierarchy?

Comment: Why you want to avoid distinct and traversal?

Comment: Because different leafs may have same parents and query does unnecessary traversal hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have list of root elements or method to detect it (parent id is null or something like that)?

Comment: No, I don't. I have only id of leafs.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible without additional stuff like adding a custom index value for every row and then calculate mathematically the things to select. But it is not native and is really heavy solution. You cannot replace this query if you do not know the height of the tree, and you will need to manually write the amount of `select` statements equals the height of the tree.

If you have problems with performance, create indices or materialized view which will collect all parents for every leave.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, if you don't know the height of the tree and don't bother with writing series of manual selects, distinct and full tree traversal is the price you have to pay. But I doubt that there is much overhead since in bottom-to-top hierarchy there is only one parent node at each level (if your hierarchy don't have loops and multiple inheritance). To estimate the ratio of unique / total ids let's take the average tree height as `h` and quantity of leafs in the list as `q`. The query output is maximum `h * q` rows in case all leafs has different parents. The minimum number of rows you can get in theory is `h + q - 1` (when all leafs in your list has the same parents). So `(h + q - 1) / (h * q)` is the ratio between distinct and total records for the worst case. You can substitute your actual values of `h` and `q` to measure possible overhead of distinct operation. As you see here we don't take in account total number of rows in the table. I assume that there is an index on parent and child id columns, so each search operation will perform well.